# Databricks Delta Live Tables Just Overwrite after CDC and SCD?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-streaming, delta-live-tables

I am facing the following issue. I use DLT to develop a pipeline with a Multihop-Architecture.

For the ingestion into the Bronze tables i use the autoloader functionality (the source is S3). For the silver table with my customer data i use the dlt.apply_changes() functions with SCD Type 2.

I also would like to compute features (gold table) from the customer silver table directly in the same DLT Pipeline but every table after using dlt.apply_changes() will be a Materialized View. (The target of the APPLY CHANGES INTO query or apply_changes function cannot be used as a source for a streaming table, see https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/cdc.html)

When the transformations for silver to gold are written in the same DLT pipeline and a new batch of data arrives, the gold table will be overwritten every time. I would like to avoid a complete overwrite in this gold table and i just want to append the data, so i dont have to transform the older data again. Is there a possibility for this?

Currently my solution is to just use DLT for the bronze and silver tables and compute the transformations in a Job-Task. (The first task is the DLT pipeline and the silver to gold transformations are the next tasks). Is there another possibility to handle this issue?

Comment: In order to have table as source for streaming they should be append only. Apply change basically does merges data so it is not append only.